# Error parsing xml in android

Tags: android, xml

So im trying to parse and xml file in android. Bellow is a link to the file and my code. I'm trying to get the current temp stored as "temp_f" in the "current_conditions" element. But every time i run it i get this error, `09-15 20:26:47.359: DEBUG/ErOr(17663): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl`

http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=10598

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory1.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
            InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmltemp));
            Document doc = factory1.newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);

            String newstring = "" + ((DocumentBuilderFactory) ((Document) doc.getDocumentElement().
               getElementsByTagName("current_conditions").item(0)).
               getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0)).
               getAttribute("data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Java XPath API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description) -- that should be much nicer than traversing the DOM to find your data:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=10598");
InputSource xml = new InputSource(url.openStream());
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String data = xpath.evaluate("//current_conditions/temp_f/@data", xml);
```

---

**As for the original question:**

First put every statement of your extraction code on a *line of its own*, this will help you a lot with finding the problems (and line numbers in stacktrace will be a lot more precise):

```
Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
Document curr_cond = (Document) /*1*/ docElem.getElementsByTagName("current_conditions").item(0);
DocumentBuilderFactory temp_f = (DocumentBuilderFactory) /*2*/ curr_cond.getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0);
String newstring = "" + temp_f.getAttribute("data");
```

At `/*1*/` you try to cast a `org.w3.dom.Node` into an `org.w3.dom.Document` -- but not every `Node` is a `Document`, as can be seen by the `ClassCastException` here: The returned `Node` is actually an instance of the `org.w3.dom.Element` interface, more precisely an instance of class of `org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl` (part of the Apache Harmony XML parser implementation).

So let's remove the cast and change the declared type of `curr_cond` to `Node`:

```
Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
Node curr_cond = docElem.getElementsByTagName("current_conditions").item(0);
DocumentBuilderFactory temp_f = (DocumentBuilderFactory) /*2*/ curr_cond.getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0);
String newstring = "" + temp_f.getAttribute("data");
```

Now a second problem becomes obvious at `/*2*/`: The `Node` interface does not specify a `getElementsByTagName()` method, that's probably why you did try to cast to `Document` above. This won't compile and there is no way to get it to.

Why you cast the result to `DocumentBuilderFactory` is beyond me. Yes, there is a `getAttribute()` method but both the class name and method javadoc should have made clear that it's definitely not doing want you want.

So my above recommendation holds: Please use XPath, it's the better tool for this task :)

---

There actually **is** a way to extract the data using *only DOM* for your first task (current temperature). It relies on the fact that the `temp_f` element is unique and is a lot more verbose than the above XPath expression, though:

```
Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
Node temp_f = docElem.getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0);
NamedNodeMap attributes = temp_f.getAttributes();
Node dataAttr = attributes.getNamedItem("data");
String data = dataAttr.getNodeValue();
```

Comment: If i wanted to find the "high" for the day under the first "forecast_conditions" how would i do that. I tried using this path but it doesn't work... "//forecast_conditions/temphigh/@data"

Comment: Use `//forecast_conditions[1]/high/@data` -- note that XPath indices look like those of a Java array, but are 1-based.